# .htaccess - лишние слэши после имени домена

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте!
У меня такой вопрос возник по причине того, что на моём хостинге, управляемым сервером apache, после имени домена можно добавить бесконечное число слэшей, и сайт всё равно открывается.

Пример:

```
http://имя_моего_домена//////имя_директории
```

Хотелось бы убрать все эти слэши так, чтобы было перенаправление на страницу без слэшей, т.е.

```
http://имя_моего_домена/имя_директории
```

Но проблема в том, что `RewriteRule` правила не видят множество слэшей именно после имени домена и избавиться от них можно, только пользуясь одним редиректом на ту же страницу (R=301).
В связи с этим вопрос - если нельзя проверить никакие особые условия по содержанию самой `URI`, то каким ещё образом можно выполнить редирект только один раз во всём цикле обработки, а при возвращении к первому правилу обработки условий после редиректа просто пропускать существующий редирект каждый последующий раз?

Comment: У вас не wordpress случаем?

Comment: Ну так можете попробовать вставить в код такую регулярку для удаления лишних слешей:

    preg_replace("#(?<!^http:)/{2,}#i","/",$url);

Писал не сам, в регулярных особо не шарю, но у меня работает. Может ее можно как-нибудь и .htaccess вставить, может кто более опытный подскажет

Comment: Код, анализирующий входящий REQUEST_URI. В случае нахожления дублей, редирект на исправленный URI. Может не сильно эффективно, но вроде работает без проблем. Может кто более опытный в mod_rewrite покажет как применить в  .htaccess? Подождите, может кто ответит.

Comment: Вероятнее всего у Вас все запросы идут на роутер, который игнорирует слэши в начале пути. Просто измените роутер так, чтобы он их не игнорировал, а получались обычные невалидные адреса, тогда никто не будет добавлять бесконечное число слешей в начало адресов на страницы Вашего сайта.

Comment: Спасибо, но не могли бы вы мне поточнее подсказать, что вы имеете ввиду под словом роутер и где в таком случае вероятнее всего прописано поведение этого самого роутера? Т.е. куда лезть на сервере и что исправлять? К httpd.conf доступа не имею.

Comment: Я пробовал избавляться от слешей путём использования серверных переменных ENV в htaccess, но с ними почему-то не получается правильно проверять условия совместно с rewriterule, а проверка работает только в том случае, когда я сделаю всевозможные указания на остановку процесса преобразования или на запрещение страницы

    RewriteCond %{ENV:FINISH} ^1$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

А вот такое уже не проходит:

    RewriteCond %{ENV:FINISH} ^1$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1

Comment: @ReinRaus имеет ввиду, что все адреса, имеющие лишние слеши должны выдавать 404 ошибку, в принципе, решение неплохое, если вы перенаправляете все URI на index.php, а уже в нем формируете по REQUEST_URI страницу.

Comment: @MDJHD ну напишу я правило, выдающее 404 по лишним слешам, но проблема заключается не в лишних слешах в принципе, а в том, что лишние слеши после имени домена всё равно воспринимаются как один слеш, и я хотел узнать, либо как от этого избавиться, либо какой-то способ запустить редирект страницы саму на себя только один раз по какой-то условной переменной, чтобы не происходило циклической переадресации.
У меня и так вся ссылка преобразуется по определённым правилам и в конце запрос идёт на страницу `default.html?url=имя_uri`, а в адресной строке отображается обработанная url по моим правилам.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [здесь](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes), возможно решение вашей проблемы в этом параметре сервера

Comment: @MDJHD http://nginx.org/
У меня apache

Comment: а какой у вас хостер, если не секрет, сейчас просто многие ставят nginx и apache в связке? Ну и повторюсь с php-обработкой проблемы:

     if(strpos('//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) !== false){
         $uri = preg_replace('#/{2,}#', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
         header('Location: '.$uri, false, 301);
         exit;
     }

Comment: Ну можно и средствами php реализовать, да, просто хотелось сразу всё в .htaccess оставить по обработке вида ссылок и направления.
Хостер Bluehost.com